# Invertible function $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$

Tags: functions

I am trying to find out if it is possible to create an invertible function from $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$?

Can you help me? Where should I start? Is it related with the Cantor pairing function?

Answer (score 3):

The following function, used to produce a total order on $\mathbf N^*$ different from the usual order, is a bijection:
\begin{align*}
\mathbf N\times\mathbf N&\longrightarrow\mathbf N^*\\
(n,p)&\longmapsto 2^n(2p+1)
\end{align*}
Hence the function
$$f(n,p)= 2^n(2p+1)-1$$
satisfies the requirements.

Comment: I saw that example on the internet, but I do not understand how to prove that this function has an inverse function. So I did : f(x,y)=59 so f(x,y)=2^x*(2x+1)-1=59 it becomes f(x,y)=2^x*(2x+1)+60. Now if we factorize 60 it becomes :  f(x,y)=2^x*(2x+1)+2*5^2,after that I don't know how to proceed can anyone help? thanks

Comment: Can you help me on the comment above? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Cantor pairing function is exactly an example of an invertible function $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, so you need to just show that it is invertible.  The wikipedia page on the Cantor Pairing function provides such an inverse, but it's probably a good exercise to see if you can find it yourself first.

(That being said, there are *many* invertible functions from $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$.)

Answer (score 0):

think about the following
let $f$ map $(0,0) \to 0, (0,1)\to 1, (1,0) \to 2, (2,0) \to 3, (1,1) \to 4$ etc. Continue following these diagonal-like paths until the entire $\mathbb{N}^2$ is covered. $f$ is a bijection...